# Cómo puedo hacer subrutas; que estén protegidas

Tags: reactjs

Tengo que añadir a cada subruta => "PrivateRoute" o hay otra manera de añadirlas dentro de un "PrivateRoute"?

Pense en esto:

```
<PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path="/Dashboard" exact>
    <Route component={Sub} path="/Dashboard/sub" exact />
</PrivateRoute>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una ruta privada, que hace de wrapper de tu componente con la ruta:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        user.loggedIn  ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Y puedes usarlo asi:

```
  <PrivateRoute
    component={Dashboard}
    exact
    path="/dashboard"
  />
```

Comment: Podrias usar un arreglo con tus rutas privadas y y hacer unu map con un router, quedaria algo asi:                 [
    {
      path: "/home",
      component: Home,
      name: "Home",
      exact: true,
      strict: true
    }, ...]                                                                                        
 <Switch>
        {routes.map(route => (
          <PrivateRoute key={route.path} {...route} />
        ))}
      </Switch>